# Qt C++ - Can't add slots

Tags: c++, qt

When I add slots to my script it will no longer build.

`inkpuppet.obj:-1: error: LNK2005: "private: void __cdecl InkPuppet::on_aboutButton_clicked(void)" (?on_aboutButton_clicked@InkPuppet@@AEAAXXZ) already defined in main.obj`

and

`debug\InkPuppet.exe:-1: error: LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found`

Here is the code:

inkpuppet.h - commenting out `void on_aboutButton_clicked();` and the function at the end will make it run.

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QtCore>

namespace Ui {
class InkPuppet;
}

class InkPuppet : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT



public:
    explicit InkPuppet(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~InkPuppet();

private:
    Ui::InkPuppet *ui;

private slots:
    void on_aboutButton_clicked();
};

#endif // WIDGET_H


void InkPuppet::on_aboutButton_clicked()
{

}
```

inkpuppet.cpp

```
#include "inkpuppet.h"
#include "ui_inkpuppet.h"


InkPuppet::InkPuppet(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::InkPuppet)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //connect(ui->lowerFrameBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), ui->timeSlider, SLOT(setRange(int,int)));
}

InkPuppet::~InkPuppet()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "inkpuppet.h"
#include "aboutdialog.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    InkPuppet w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

aboutdialog.h

```
#ifndef ABOUTDIALOG_H
#define ABOUTDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class AboutDialog;
}

class AboutDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit AboutDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~AboutDialog();

private:
    Ui::AboutDialog *ui;
};

#endif // ABOUTDIALOG_H
```

aboutdialog.cpp

```
#include "aboutdialog.h"
#include "ui_aboutdialog.h"

AboutDialog::AboutDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::AboutDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

AboutDialog::~AboutDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: it's a little wierd by definition your method after #endif, by the way change private solts to public slots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define your `void InkPuppet::on_aboutButton_clicked()` in your inkpuppet.h. And then you include it in inkpuppet.cpp AND in main.cpp ->  one or more multiply defined symbols found.

Put

```
void InkPuppet::on_aboutButton_clicked()
{

}
```

in your inkpuppet.cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

If the first file you pasted is a whole, there's a problem with the include guards. The definition is *after* the guard's end.

```
#endif // WIDGET_H

void InkPuppet::on_aboutButton_clicked()
{

}
```

Your definition is right after the `#endif` which means as soon as in the same translation unit, the header is included twice, you'll get this error. And this happens in your code because `inkpuppet.h` is included in both `main.cpp` and in `inkpuppet.cpp` You should put the implementation code for `on_aboutButton_clicked()` in your `inkpuppet.cpp` file.